# How could I set a description for all users at the same OU?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, users

I'm trying to use the output from write-output command and use Set-ADUser to change Descripton field from all Users on a specific OU.

First I did:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU="Users",ou="Customer10",OU="Customers",OU="Company",DC=domain,DC=net' -Filter * | Select SamAccountName
Write-Output $users
```

Which way I could handle the next command to add the description?
Tried a foreach:
`foreach ($usuarios in $users)` - between the command bellow without success.

Set-ADuser -Identity $users -Description "Customer 10 - Customer"

It seems that does not Identify the SamAccountName by the Identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Set-ADUsers` command wouldn't work because it is trying to use your $Users object which contains all your users you are searching for.  The ForEach needs to work with one at a time.  I would also drop the `| Select-Object SamAccountName` as well, so you can work with the full object and properties later in the script if needed.  I would do something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU="Users",ou="Customer10",OU="Customers",OU="Company",DC=domain,DC=net' -Filter *
Write-Output $users 
ForEach ($usuarios in $users) {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $usuarios.SamAccountName -Description "Customer 10 - Customer"
}
```

Comment: I'm using the same user with Admin powers but it returns:
Set-ADUser : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation

Comment: Did worked fine running with Administrator prompt, just running by ISE not worked.